# Deeplens v1 Registration Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-deeplens

I followed all the steps to register a v1 deeplens without any errors, but when I go back to the console, it shows registration status as failed. I did the process multiple times, using different networks, but it still doesn't work. Sometimes, the process would get stuck on 'checking your registration" but other times it just shows that registration failed. Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question. We don't have any access to your account at an off-site vendor or service, and can't answer questions related to that account. Contact the vendor's customer service for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using the below steps:

1. de-registered the device with failed registration status
2. attached a keyboard and  monitor to the camera and logged in using the password I created during the initial registration attempt (if you haven't set that password then the default should be aws-cam)
3. opened cmd on the camera and ran the below commands to update it:

> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install awscam

> sudo reboot

4. Once the camera was rebooted, I inserted a pin in the reset hole in the camera
5. did the registration process all over again and it was successful